# Writing test code for verifying database entries when testing an API

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, junit, automated-tests, client-server

I'm writing test code to test a client-server application. The application under test consists of

1. an application that runs on Tomcat
   or another Java EE application server, and
2. client jars that expose an API.

I'm basically writing test code that uses this client API to connect to the server.

In addition to extensively testing the API operations, my superiors have advised me to connect to the database on the server and verify that fields are being populated properly. I have done that for some of my test cases, but it hasn't really caught any bugs during regression.

Bugs are caught when a particular functionality fails, but that anyway gets revealed in the code that tests the API itself. It seems that DB data verification is not really useful, especially considering the extra effort required to write and maintain all that code.

**My question is:**

Is there any real benefit to write test code for connecting to the DB and verifying entries in this manner? Do the benefits pay off for the costs incurred in writing such code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the database is unnecessary for such tests. You can achieve better results by testing that:

1. Save requests return a success status.
2. Get requests return the saved data.
3. The saved data is returned by a get request even after you reset client state ie. take client-side caching into consideration.

If you test the database contents, your test cannot be used to see if a change in the database works, because the tests expect a certain state in the database. If this is changed, your tests fail, even if the system works.

Comment: Very true regarding the database state changes. I have had to spend time correcting the test cases because of changes in the database schema.

Comment: Testing the database like this is testing for side-effects. You should investigate why your superiors think that a working API needs side-effect testing? and explain that such testing does not increase reliability.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the database may find bugs, but it's not very likely, so I would keep the checking of the database to a minimum. As long as the API saves and restores data correctly, you don't really care how it has been stored.

You can check the database, but personally I would not do this in a systematic way.

You're asking the right questions, the purpose of testing is to find bugs. How many bugs have you found with this testing?

Automated regression testing is sometimes looked upon as a no-cost thing, but if you're continually having to update the tests then it isn't.

If you're unhappy at having to maintain these tests, I would record how much time you're spending doing it, and then you can argue that you could be doing more productive work instead, doing other forms of testing, or development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, MatthieuF. Unfortunately, I can choose only one answer, so I'm choosing the answer that came first.

Answer (score 0):

With such kind of tests you are verifying the content of the database. The other tests only verify the API operations but not the results into the DB.

Comment: The point is that, after I send some data using the API, I use the API calls themselves to retrieve most of the data and then I verify what I get. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: But this is testing multiple levels in once and not level by level. Starting with API putting something into the API and checking the result in the DB. Then fetching something from the DB and giving it back via the API. These are at least two levels you can test and in my opinion you should test.

Comment: That could be a good point...but isn't it really covered by the API testing? If the steps outlined by jmz are followed, the API will eventually give the same data back.

To me, the two levels of testing feels like performing the same test in two different ways, with one way (the API way) being a superset of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Asking an API to verify itself is like asking someone if they are honest and having them answer "because I am honest" and accepting that. It is circular reasoning. Is there a way out of this loop? It makes me feel uneasy to accept the results of something whose correctness has not been thoroughly tested.